# Running psql with a role

Tags: command-line, postgresql

When using psql I always have to issue `set role ...` first.

Could this be executed automatically before accepting interactive commands?

E.g.:

```
psql -h HOST -U USER -c "set role 'ROLE';" -f -
```

This almost does what I want except that it reads the input directly (without readline).

I can't use `-U ROLE` because the role is not allowed to log in.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe what happens if you try: `psql -h HOST -U ROLE`.  Note that `-U` must be upper case.

Comment: @JimL. I can't use -U ROLE because the role is not allowed to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unless it is passed an -X option, psql attempts to read and execute commands from the system-wide startup file (psqlrc) and then the user's personal startup file (~/.psqlrc), after connecting to the database but before accepting normal commands.

and:

> ENVIRONMENT       PSQLRC          Alternative location of the user's .psqlrc file. Tilde (~) expansion is performed.

So you can just create a set-role.sql file:

```
set role 'ROLE';
```

and then run

```
PSQLRC=set-role.sql psql -h HOST -U USER
```

psql will execute the set command and then show a prompt (with autocomplete).

Comment: Expanding this slightly, you can use virtual file handles in bash (and probably other shells): `PSQLRC=<(echo "SET role 'ROLE'") psql ...` Then inside the session, you should see that role.